# When i add orderBy app is not working in firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

> Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: Error: The query requires an index. You
>   can create it here at new FirestoreError (index.cjs.js:352)
>       at JsonProtoSerializer.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromRpcStatus
>   (index.cjs.js:5862)
>       at JsonProtoSerializer.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.JsonProtoSerializer.fromWatchChange
>   (index.cjs.js:6359)
>       at PersistentListenStream.push../node_modules/@firebase/firestore/dist/index.cjs.js.PersistentListenStream.onMessage
>   (index.cjs.js:14974)
>       at index.cjs.js:14903
>       at index.cjs.js:14943
>       at index.cjs.js:7656
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:388)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:13851)
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:387)

My code

```
this.firestore.collection('mycollection').ref
        .orderBy("created","desc")
        .where("field","==",true) 
    <br>
```

but when i remove orderby app work fine

```
this.firestore.collection('mycollection').ref 
        .where("field","==",true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error shall contain a link on which you can click to create the said index. You just have to click on it and wait.